# ES module not transpiled by babel and webpack, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

In my bundle output, a specific ES module was not transpiled, and UglifyJsPlugin throw the error `Unexpected token: keyword «const»`

I have tried explicitly including the module in the rule. I am not using `exclude: /node_modules/`

in Webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
},
```

I would expect the ES module, which was bundled by rollup, to be transpiled when used in my main project which has babel enabled.

Comment: share git link to your project

Comment: It's a private repo

Comment: could you make it public?